# React-Native Meteor: Fetching data from database

Tags: meteor, react-native

Im building my first React-Native app With Meteor. I'm trying to fetch data from the database but I can't get it to work. I only have the handle with ready and stop properties but it doesn't contain any object data. Could someone explain how I can get the actual data from my database?

Container in the component:

```
export default createContainer(() => {
  const handle = Meteor.subscribe('details-list');
  return {
    detailsReady: handle.ready(),
  };
}, DetailsContainer);
```

Export in meteor app

```
export default () => {
  Meteor.publish('details-list', () => {
    return Details.find();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the data you want in the container, something like this:

`export default createContainer(() => {
  const handle = Meteor.subscribe('details-list');
  return {
    details: Details.find(),
    detailsReady: handle.ready(),
  };
}, DetailsContainer);`

Comment: When I do this it says It can't find the module Details. When I try to import it I get the error unable to resolve module although I'm sure the file path is correct. Any idea?

Comment: Replacing Details.find() in Meteor.collection('details').find() solved the problem